# Selenium::WebDriver::Error::ElementNotVisibleError while looping to click button using Watir

Tags: ruby, rspec, watir, watir-webdriver

I am trying to click a button on loop basis.

Let us say I have following code

```
if ind == 2
  export_id = @browser.div(:id => pop_id).div(:class => /actionDropDownItem groupChild nonSelectable/,:title => "Export").id
  @browser.div(:id => export_id).click
else
  @browser.div(:id => pop_id).div(:class => /actionDropDownItem groupChild nonSelectable/,:title => "Export").click
end
```

But it shows error at index value "2" and the Error is

```
Selenium::WebDriver::Error::ElementNotVisibleError:
Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with
```

Can anyone help me in this case?

Comment: The exception says the element is not visible. You likely need to do some other action to make it visible - eg hovering over a dropdown menu. Without seeing the page it is difficult to tell you the exact problem.

Comment: In many cases, trying something like sleep 2 before clicking the element turned out to work. Try telling Ruby to wait a sec or two before trying to click it.

Comment: @daremkd I tried with sleep and wait_until_present but still it fails and teh ID it is getting is aslo a wrong one

Comment: Have you tried finding the element by xpath? Try writing xpath expression, there was one site where I got this error and finding the element using xpath expression did the job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be great if you provide proper html .

Try this once , this would work for you

```
if ind == 2
  export_id = @browser.div(:id => export_id)
  export_id.click
else
  @browser.div(:id => pop_id).div(:class => /actionDropDownItem groupChild nonSelectable/,:title => "Export").click
end
```